# Closing Dropdown Menu by Clicking Outside the Box

Tags: javascript, html, css

Whenever I click on "Urunler" in the menu I created I can successfully open and close the dropdown menu under "Urunler". When I click outside the box it also successfully closes the dropdown menu. In order to regenerate the problem I am facing do this and see yourself.

1)Click on "Urunler" and make sure dropdown menu is opened.
2)Click on somewhere outside the dropdown menu and "Urunler" and make sure dropdown menu is closed.
3)Click on "Urunler" again to open up the dropdown menu.

It does not open the dropdown menu in the first attempt but the second one works.

I am a complete noob and I dont really know what I am doing. I tried going through the topic in Javascript called variable scopes but could not really get the reason why the glitch happens.

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF8">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="180">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <img src="logo.jpg" alt="Smiley face" id="logo"> 
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Anasayfa</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Hakkımızda</a></li>
                <li id="products"><a href="#">Ürünler</a>
                    <ul id="dropdown" class="dropdownMenu">
                        <li><a href="#">Ürün 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Ürün 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Ürün 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Ürün 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">İletişim</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    
    <script src="main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /* Width and height apply to all parts of the element: content, padding and borders */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#menu{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

#logo{
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
}

div nav{
    display: flex;
  /* This flexbox property lets button area to fill-in the remainin space until the logo area */
    flex: 1; 
}

div nav ul{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: mediumaquamarine;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex: 1; 
  /* This flexbox property lets button area to fill-in the remainin space until the logo area */
}

div nav ul li{
    display: flex; /* These 3 lines or the align the bottons vertically */
    flex-direction: column; /* These 3 lines or the align the bottons vertically */
    justify-content: center; /* These 3 lines or the align the bottons vertically */
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: blue;
    flex: 1; 
  /* This flexbox property lets button area to fill-in the remainin space until the logo area */
    position: relative;

}

div nav ul li a{
    display: flex; /* These 3 lines or the align the bottons vertically */
    flex-direction: column; /* These 3 lines or the align the bottons vertically */
    justify-content: center; /* These 3 lines or the align the bottons vertically */
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: orange;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0.5px;
}

div nav ul li a:hover{
    background-color: #9f7934;
}

.dropdownMenu{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    top: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

Javascript

```
var value = 0;
document.getElementById("products").addEventListener("click", dropShow);
window.addEventListener("mouseup", dropHide);


function dropShow(){
    if(value == 0){
        document.getElementById("dropdown").style.overflow = "visible";
        document.getElementById("dropdown").style.height = "200px";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("dropdown").style.overflow = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("dropdown").style.height = "0px";
    }
    
    if(value == 0){
        value = 1;
    }else{
        value = 0;
    }
}



function dropHide(){  
    document.getElementById("dropdown").style.overflow = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("dropdown").style.height = "0px";
}
```

When clicked outside the box how to make the dropdown menu open up with a single click? I would be appreciated for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Hi the problem happens because your flag (value variable) is not set to proper state on dropHide function. However there are lots of possible optimizations to your code and I tried to show you one a better way in below fiddle:

You do not need variable as flag you can use a class for it for example .show class and this will allow you to make use of classList methods to toggle remove - add it this way you get rid of inline css too.

// JS

```
document.addEventListener("click", toggleDropdown);

function toggleDropdown(event) {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown");

    if (event.target.classList.contains('urunler')){
        dropdown.classList.toggle('show');
    } else {
        dropdown.classList.remove('show');
    }
```

// CSS

```
.dropdownMenu.show {
  overflow:visible;
  height:200px;
}
```

// HTML

```
 <li id="products" class="products"><a href="#" class="urunler">Ürünler</a>
                <ul id="dropdown" class="dropdownMenu">
                    <li><a href="#">Ürün 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ürün 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ürün 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ürün 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6azurh7L/1/

Comment: Thank you Orek. Do you know why transition method does not apply when the dropdown menu opens? When closing you see a little animation but it does not happen when it opens up.

Comment: You are welcome, in the fiddle I shared transition exists. 
You can take a look to the link https://jsfiddle.net/6azurh7L/1/

Comment: Are you sure you shared the correct link? Seems like there is no animation. By the way try to open this in Firefox. Firefox browsers do not get animation while opening.

Comment: Yes I'm sure, I don't have firefox atm but your transition should be working regardless the browser you can try increasing time of transitions and see the difference. I'm not quite sure if this is the animation you wish but there is a transition for sure

e.g increased transition time:

 -webkit-transition: all 1.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1.3s ease;
    transition: all 1.3s ease;

Comment: Not really. it instantly opens on opening but transition occurs when closed.

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit:

After looking at your fiddle and my example again, you could still use `value` if you'd like, you just need to set it to 0 in `dropHide`.

#### Original Answer:

Your problem is that you over engineered your solution.  Think about the logic of your function:

- Once clicked, check `value`.
- Depending on `value` either show or hide the dropdown.
- Then flip `value`

That's all your function does, and will ever do so it's working as it should.  When you click outside, the classes are all removed and the dropdown disappears.  The problem is that you didn't detect that and flip `value`.

Much better would be to check something that is attached to the dropdown AND is affected by a mouse click outside the dropdown.  The correct choice then, is to check whether the dropdown is hidden or not with each click and then perform the appropriate action.  No need to manually change the `value` variable as you no longer need it!  I've included an example below, enjoy!

```js
var value = 0;
document.getElementById("products").addEventListener("click", dropShow);
window.addEventListener("mouseup", dropHide);


function dropShow(){
    let myElement = document.getElementById("dropdown");
    if(myElement.style.overflow == "hidden"){
        myElement.style.overflow = "visible";
        myElement.style.height = "200px";
    }else{
        myElement.style.overflow = "hidden";
        myElement.style.height = "0px";
    }
}



function dropHide(){  
    document.getElementById("dropdown").style.overflow = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("dropdown").style.height = "0px";
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /* Width and height apply to all parts of the element: content, padding and borders */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#menu{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

#logo{
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
}

div nav{
    display: flex;
  /* This flexbox property lets button area to fill-in the remainin space until the logo area */
    flex: 1; 
}

div nav ul{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: mediumaquamarine;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex: 1; 
  /* This flexbox property lets button area to fill-in the remainin space until the logo area */
}

div nav ul li{
    display: flex; /* These 3 lines or the align the bottons vertically */
    flex-direction: column; /* These 3 lines or the align the bottons vertically */
    justify-content: center; /* These 3 lines or the align the bottons vertically */
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: blue;
    flex: 1; 
  /* This flexbox property lets button area to fill-in the remainin space until the logo area */
    position: relative;

}

div nav ul li a{
    display: flex; /* These 3 lines or the align the bottons vertically */
    flex-direction: column; /* These 3 lines or the align the bottons vertically */
    justify-content: center; /* These 3 lines or the align the bottons vertically */
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: orange;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0.5px;
}

div nav ul li a:hover{
    background-color: #9f7934;
}

.dropdownMenu{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    top: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <img src="logo.jpg" alt="Smiley face" id="logo"> 
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">LORUM IPSUM</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LORUM IPSUM</a></li>
                <li id="products"><a href="#">LORUM IPSUM</a>
                    <ul id="dropdown" class="dropdownMenu">
                        <li><a href="#">LORUM IPSUM 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">LORUM IPSUM 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">LORUM IPSUM 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">LORUM IPSUM 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">LORUM IPSUM</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    
    <script src="main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I actually tried this by myself too but it does not work. It messed up the "Urunler" button. If you click to "Urunler" to open up you cannot close by hitting the same button again. You can only close by clicking somewhere else.

Comment: Ah I missed that, that's simply due to your "mouseup" code fighting the "click" code.  It could be fixed by using classes for the styling rather than doing it all with raw style manipulation as another answer has shown.

Comment: Hi Mathew.. Sorry I could not find a way to send a private message. Can you please remove the meta data where it gives information about my website in your answer. I believe because of these public info I get some unknown traffic to my website from time to times. I appreciate your understanding.

Comment: @Gingercook I've edited the answer, let me know if there's any data left that you want removed.